# Minimum array value incorrect using recursion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, minimum

I am trying to create a method to search a 1D array for a minimum value using recursion. It does give me an output but it is always "1" regardless of whether or not the array even contains "1". I am very new to programming and any help is appreciated.

```
public static int smallest(int[] array)
{
    return smallestFrom(array, 0);
}

static int min = 500; //large number

private static int smallestFrom(int[] array, int i)
{ 
    int x = array.length;
    if (i < x && array[i] < min)
    {
        min = array[i];
        i++;
        smallestFrom(array, i);
    }
    else if (i < x && array[i] >= min)
    {
        i++;
        smallestFrom(array, i);
    }
    return min;

}
```

Output:

```
2,4,6,1,6,3,8
Smallest: 1

43,76,3,23,95,23
Smallest: 1
```

Comment: I just ran `int array [] = {43,76,3,23,95,23};
   int smallest =  smallestFrom(array, 0);
   
   System.out.println(smallest);`  and it returned `3`

Comment: Same for me, the code works

Comment: @Aaron It works if it's ran **once**. Run it with a second input-array, as OP did and it'll break

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation looks fine to me. Well, that's a bit too much said, but it works. You could improve this quite a bit though:

### Large Integer

Why use some arbitrary number as "large number"? This code will break for inputs with larger values than 500. You should just use the constant [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). There are no larger values possible than this one, it's named in a clear manor and it's defined by the API.

### Global variables

This is where the error occurs. Your implementation is designed for singleuse. `min` will hold 1 after running it with the first array. Since there are no numbers larger than 1 in the second example-array, it will return 1 again. This can be fixed by either resetting `min` to the original value each time `smallest` is called, or alternatively completely relinquishing it (see below).

### Branching

This problem can be solved with a lot less conditions. Instead of storing the minimum, we could use an alternate definition of the maximum of an array:

```
max({a, b, c, d, e, f}) = max({a, max({b, c, d, e, f})})
```

Looks more complicated? Actually it isn't. The idea is that the maximum of an array is the maximum of it's first elements and the maximum of all remaining elements in the array. This could now be translated a lot simpler into code.

### Putting it all together

```
static int min(int[] arr)
{
    return minRec(arr, 0);
}

static int minRec(int[] arr, int i)
{
    if(i == arr.length)
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    return Math.min(arr[i], minRec(arr, i + 1));
}
```

Looks a lot neater, doesn't it? [`Math.min(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) is just the API-implementation of a function that returns the minimum of two parameters.

Comment: So why do i need the `if(i == arr.length) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;` if MAX_VALUE is never returned? Also is there an easy way to also output index location?

Comment: @OUmSKILLS `MAX_VALUE` is returned once the algorithm reaches the end of the array. But your array contains only values smaller than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so you won't get that value as a maximum. Call the method with an empty array and you'll get `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as an result. The condition is needed to prevent the algorithm from reading outside of the array and throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. It's possible to get the index instead of the minimal value. If you want both, you'll have to use an array or additional class to wrap the result of the function calls.

Comment: @OUmSKILLS the index-part can be solved pretty easily by just getting the index of the minimal value instead of the actual minimal value. You don't need both, since you can  simply read the element at the returned index in the array, which is  your minimum. Just make `minRec` return the index of the so far minimal-value instead of the so far minimal value and update the return-statement accordingly.